# Scaling for multiple devices

Tags: objective-c, ios6, storyboard, scaling

So I am creating an app that will be released in the App Store available for iPhone 4/4s and iPhone 5.

In my project I am using storyboard for the interface. 
At the moment not every object is able to aline perfect with the objects above so when I for example test on iphone 4 every thing gets messed up.

How can I fix the place of the object.

Do I have to hardcode this? Or can I use storyboard for this.

Comment: It depend on how u want your user interface on 3.5 and 4 inch screen better you provide some view here.

Comment: Basically I want to have it look the same on the iPhone 5 there will be some empty space at the bottom. I have an iPhone 5 as dev phone so that will be best for outgoing view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think autolayout should suffice in most cases. You can check out a comprehensive tutorial here: http://floatlearning.com/2012/11/designing-for-multiple-screens-in-ios/

Comment: perfect thanks this is works like i want it with fixed positions